# "Type JsonProvider is not defined" in fsx script

Tags: f#

In my .fsx script I have:

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"
open FSharp.Data

type appSettings = JsonProvider<"C:\\Users\\me\\schema\\sample.json">
```

This generates an error of `Type JsonProvider not defined` both in the IDE and when I build it using `dotnet fsi`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Works for me if I fully qualify JsonProvider. That seems strange, for sure.

Comment: Can you post the full text to the error/exception that's being thrown?

Comment: What happens if you fully qualify the version `#r "nuget: FSharp.Data, 5.0.2"`?